# Swap bundles in 0x Protocol

Tags: polygon, 0x

Do you know if future updates of the protocol will allow to swap NFT bundles as in version V3 of the protocol? I would be very interested in that functionality but I can't use the v3 version because it is not supported by Polygon.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

It should work on Polygon for V3.

Here are the v3 contract addresses:
https://github.com/trader-xyz/nft-swap-sdk/blob/5782d110b8882f7490f33b80acf59cd6f2ea7301/src/sdk/v3/addresses.json

Here is a test on Mumbai for `nft-swap-sdk` using 0x v3:
https://github.com/trader-xyz/nft-swap-sdk/blob/8b3c3ebfa868cbbb1beb59f49521b956faed0201/test/v3/multi-asset-swap.test.ts

Answer (score 0):

The v3 version works on Polygon. I didn't try on polygon but I tried on mumbai.